# Apache LocationMatch does not work for group

Tags: apache-2.2, regex

I would like to configure Apache to proxy mldonkey running at localhost. Initially I have used the following configuration (in server config):

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
    <LocationMatch /(mldonkey|bittorrent)/>
        ProxyPass           http://localhost:4080/
        ProxyPassReverse    http://localhost:4080/
    </LocationMatch>
</IfModule>
```

and it didn't worked! `error.log` reads `[error] [client 192.168.1.1] File does not exist: /var/www/mldonkey` which means that Apache does not intersect the URL. The URL I test is: `http://myserver/mldonkey/`. I also tried `http://myserver/mldonkey` (I won't expect it to work, but OK if it would work as well).

However, when I change the regexp to following:

`<LocationMatch /mldonkey/>`

it started to work (i.e. `mod_proxy` functions OK, more over all ). I have tried the following alternatives:

```
<LocationMatch ^/(mldonkey|bittorrent)/>
<LocationMatch ^/(mldonkey|bittorrent)/.*>
<LocationMatch ^/(mldonkey|bittorrent)>
<LocationMatch /(mldonkey|bittorrent)>
<LocationMatch "^/(mldonkey|bittorrent)/">
<LocationMatch "/(mldonkey|bittorrent)">
<LocationMatch "/(mldonkey)">
<LocationMatch "/(mldonkey)/">
```

with no positive result. I am stuck. Please give me a hint where to look at.

P.S. Apache Server 2.2.19.

P.P.S. Would be happy if `<LocationMatch>` would work, without using the heavy artillery of `mod_rewrite`.

Comment: Can you provide a URL that you would want to match ?

Comment: Where did you put that configuration?

Comment: Thanks for relative questions (I've updated the question): (1) the setting is in server conf (**not** in `.htaccess`) (2) I test using `http://myserver/mldonkey/` (where `myserver` is the local domain of Apache Server, MLDonkey is running at the same host).